# Dispatching multiple actions with @ngrx/effects while making sure they are executed in order

Tags: angular, rxjs5, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I'm curious if there is any way to ensure order of actions in `@ngrx/effects` when returning multiple actions as response to some other one.

`ActionA => emit ActionB (=> emit async ActionB1, ActionB2) and then ActionC`

I would like to achieve sequence of `ActionA`, `ActionB`, `ActionB1`, `ActionB2`, `ActionC`.

One can use `concatMap` but that doesn't seem to ensure, that actions B1 and B2 were being handled prior to emitting C.

Real world example:

```
@Effect()
oauthLoginAsSomeoneElse$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType<AuthActions.OAuthLoginAsSomeoneElse>(AuthActions.OAUTH_LOGIN_AS_SOMEONE_ELSE)
    .pipe(
        concatMap(action => [
            // First logout
            new AuthActions.OAuthLogout(),
            // Then login again
            new AuthActions.OAuthLogin({redir: action.payload.redir})
        ])
    );

@Effect({dispatch: false})
oauthLogin$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType<AuthActions.OAuthLogin>(AuthActions.OAUTH_LOGIN)
    .pipe(
        map(action => oauthRedir.start(
            this.authEndpoint + '/oauth/authorize',
            this.authClientId,
            this.authRedirectUri,
            this.appBaseHref,
            action.payload.redir,
        ))
    );

@Effect()
oauthLogout$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType<AuthActions.OAuthLogout>(AuthActions.OAUTH_LOGOUT)
    .pipe(
        switchMap(action =>
            this.http.post(`${this.authEndpoint}/logout`, null, {withCredentials: true}).pipe(
                map(responseData => new AuthActions.SessionTerminate()),
                catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                    return of(new RouterActions.Go({path: ['/']}));
                }),
            )
        )
    );
```

You would expect, that when dispatching `OAuthLoginAsSomeoneElse` everything related to `OAuthLogout` action will be finished (including some async stuff in actions it's `@Effect()` emits) before emitting `OAuthLogin` again. I mean, first process first root action and it's children, then process next emitted root action.

Do you know how this scenario can be achieved? My current workaround is to supply next action to emit as parameter to `OAuthLogout`, but this doesn't really scale well and gets quickly quite complicated to reason about.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit late but still up to date. You can use effects to determine the order of actions triggered, even without side-http-requests or something else. This way you can easily set up a sequence of actions. With the latest NgRX effects syntax this would somehow look like the following:

At first set up an effect that says trigger `actionB` after `actionA`.

```js
effect1$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(actionA),
  mapTo(actionB())
));
```

After the execution of actionB you can define that it should trigger `actionB1`. You can also pass the payload around.

```js
effect2$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(actionB),
  map(payload => actionB1(payload)
));
```

Of course there should be proper effect names and so on. But hopefully you get the point. Just use `ofType` and `map` to specify the order.

---

In case of your real world example, you would need the "response" actions as well, like `loginSuccess`, `loginFailed`, `logoutSuccess`, etc. With these in place just use the above methodology to create a well defined sequence of actions.